# Bootstrap menu - borders not in one line

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bottom menu made in Bootstrap. I would like to have this menu with a white top border, so I set navbar-default border-top to 2px solid white. When I hover a mouse over a link on the menu it's border should appear. And it appears, but it's not in one line with whole navbar's border:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYXON.jpg

What can I do to make it appear in one line? I would like to have my top borders all in one line.

CSS code is simple:

```
.navbar-default {
  background: rgba(16,16,16,0.9);
  border-top: 2px solid white;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: white;
  transition: all .4s;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:active {
  color: rgb(145,64,162);
  border-top: 2px solid rgb(145,64,162);
}
```

If there's a need to show full html and css code I'll try to put it on jsfiddle, but I think the above code should be enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Full Edit after receiving codepen link:**

Here's a working copy. I believe the only downside of this solution is that you can't use your css transition on the border.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VvgZyL?editors=110

The main change was to add `margin-top: -2px;` to the hovers so that the `a` border covers up the `navbar-default` border.

And I changed your transition to `transition: color .4s;` from `all` because the border transition was making it bounce.

Comment: Oh, already tried that. But this is the effect I get: http://i.imgur.com/t69Kseq.jpg, while I would like to have this white border on whole width of my navbar, not just above menu buttons.

Comment: This will unfortunately have the side-effect of not having the white border all the way across, but just above each link :( I could work on a solution for that if you put together the jsfiddle so i can see the navbar html.

Comment: I put the code on codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EVrYXr. Hope it'll do for you.

Comment: @mentor93 Thank you for that, I've updated my answer.